# 誕生日の入力を要求するプログラムで、誕生日（◯月◯日）以外の値が入力された時の処理文の書き方を教えて頂きたいです。

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、誕生日の入力を要求しています。仮に誕生日が1月1日であれば、「誕生日は元日ですね」と表示させ、それ以外の日付であれば、入力された誕生日を表示させるようにしています。
ただ、ユーザーが誤って、「◯月◯日」以外の形式で入力することも考えられ、その際には「正しい形で入力してください」と表示させたいです。その時の処理をどう書けば良いか、教えて頂ければ幸いです。
try,cathchで作って見ましたが、今のままだと、例えば「りんご」と入力したら、「誕生日はりんごです」と表示されてしまいます。

```
package name;
import java.util.*;  //米印必須。もしくはjava.util.Scanner

public class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        System.out.println("あなたの名前を入力してください");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
        
            while(true){
            System.out.println("誕生日はいつですか？数字は半角で◯月◯日の形で入れてください>");
            Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);//誕生日を入力
            try{
                String birthday=sr.nextLine();
                if(birthday.equals("1月1日")){System.out.println("あなたの誕生日は元日ですね");}
                else {System.out.println("誕生日は"+birthday+"です");}
            }
            catch
                (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println("エラーです。中断します");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

実行環境は以下の通りです。
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: 単に「月」と「日」が含まれていればよいのか、それとも「12月32日」等のあり得ない日付は弾くのか、辺りの仕様をはっきりさせた方が回答も具体的に付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: 入力処理を1回だけに限る必要はあるのでしょうか？ 入力を1回だけ・かつ'月'・'日'も入力させるから複雑になるのでは？ 月・日それぞれの数値だけを別々に入力させれば簡単になるような気がしますが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try - catch で動かないのは、「入力が◯月◯日以外の形式だったら例外を投げる」というコードがないからです。

例外を投げるようにコードを変更してもよいですが、単純に `if` で分岐すればよいでしょう。

```java
Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);  // 誕生日を入力
String birthday = sr.nextLine();
if (birthdayが"◯月◯日"という形式ではなかったら) {
    System.out.println("エラーです。中断します");
    continue;
}
if (birthday.equals("1月1日")){
    System.out.println("あなたの誕生日は元日ですね");
} else {
    System.out.println("誕生日は" + birthday + "です");
}
```

形式のチェックは正規表現でやるのが簡単かもしれません。例: `\d{1,2}月\d{1,2}日`
ありえない日付も除外するなら、別の方法が必要です。

Comment: if (birthdayが"◯月◯日"という形式ではなかったら)→このような形式だとコンパイルエラーが起きると思います。それとも、try catchの中のif文でしょうか？できれば全てのコードを見せてもらえるとありがたいです。

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa その部分は自分でコードを書いてください。私はそこのコードは書いてないので、見せられません。